# Kafka offset confusion (consumer side)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have been reading about Kafka recently and new to it. Many places say, Kafka will never track the `offset` of a partition and the client must remember this state. One such place is this
`https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaHowMessages.html`
On the above page it says this

```
Topic partitions contain an ordered set of messages and each message in the partition has a unique offset. 
Kafka does not track which messages were read by a task or consumer.
```

However, I was reading other sources, such as this
https://kafka.apache.org/36/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

And another source(lost the link) that says that using the unique triplet of
`groupId, topic, partition` we can use different offset commit strategies which can lead to scenarios like `exactly once`, `at least once`, etc. They explain the pros and cons of
`auto-commit` vs `commitSync` vs `commitAsync` which made me believe that as long as the above triplet is specified and the commit API is used, even if my client(say running in K8 docker container), crashes and a new instance comes up, I can just this offset from the Kafka itself(basically I don't even have to worry), I will just start reading from the proper offset(of course scenarios of exactly once, lost message, at least once come into play).

So which one is it? Is the DataStax link accurate? I have read it at more than one place.
It is very confusing now. Some spring boot with Kafka articles do talk about this commit scenarios as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with datastax but the decision is up to you - keep track of the offsets externally and perform seeks when the app starts, or let Kafka keep track of the last comitted offset and it sets the position to it automatically when the consumer starts again.

Most folks choose the latter (and it is Spring's default behavior).

Maybe datastax does the former.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell, so basically Kafka does support "commitSync", "commitAsync" and "auto commit". I can commit one synchronously or many asynch or just let it auto commit after I do a batch pull right? I know these give rise to chances of lost message, reply etc scenarios and the onus is on app to be aware of it and deal with it. Is that the right gist?

Comment: Spring prefers **not** setting `enable.auto.commit` to `true`; unlike the `kafka-clients` default, Spring turns it off, unless it has been explicitly set. This is because the container commits the offset in a more deterministic manner; the preferred `AckMode`s are `BATCH` (default) and `RECORD`. With `BATCH`, the offsets of all records in the batch are committed after the last record is processed; with `RECORD`, the offset is committed after each record. `BATCH` is less overhead, but increases the possibility of duplicate deliveries after a catastrophic failure (e.g. power lost).

Comment: You should never lose records with auto commit turned off.

Comment: Russel, one follow-up. If in spring-boot, we do Batch mode, and say we dequeued 10 messages, how do we track if each is processed? Use use executor and do join? I can create a separate question for this as it might be a long answer. I hope my question is clear. I really need to know what you wrote here. It seems very useful to know

Comment: You should process records sequentially on the listener thread. Handing off to other threads will add significant complexity. To achieve concurrency, add more partitions and increase the container concurrency. However, as long as you don't exit the listener method until all tasks are complete, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Both are accurate. Kafka **brokers** do not track offsets (*on their own*). Consumers are responsible for storing this information back into Kafka, explicitly.

As written in the Datastax page

> Consumers must track their own location within each log;

Yes, consumer groups do this. Framework is irrelevant

Worth pointing out, you're reading a page about **Kafka Connect** sink connectors

> the Datastax Connector task store the offsets in config.offset.topic

That's not anything related to core consumer API. Most source connectors store offsets back in an "offsets topic", and sink connectors use `__consumer_offsets` topic, just like all other consumer groups

Comment: is Kafka Connect sink connectors something different? Also, `__consumer_offsets` topic is still on Kafka cluster side and updated via `commitSync` or `commitAsynic` or 'auto commit` right? Your message is helpful but a bit terse and little confusing to interpret fully

Comment: Your question is about Consumer API. Yes, Kafka Connect API is different, but it's still a consumer. However, offsets can be tracked differently, which is why I've used these quotes from the Datastax link you've shared (which I'm not sure why, since Kafka documentation itself is fine)